# httpd.conf: PHP, Local Value doesn't work

Tags: php, function, vhosts

I now have this when I run phpinfo():
`disable_functions: [local]=exec, [master]=shell_exec`
But I still can execute `exec` in that file where I put `phpinfo` in. Why? Local does overwrite master, doesn't it? How can I fix this?

Regards,
Kevin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [**`disable_functions`**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions) directive can only be set in `php.ini` -- so, I'm guessing your *local* value is just ignored by PHP, in this case.

Quoting the manual page I linked to :

> This directive must be set in php.ini
>   For example, you cannot set this in
>   httpd.conf.

Comment: Thanks. How can I accomplish this for only the domain `subdomain.domain.com` in `php.ini`?